# Fluentd tail plugin: tail all files in a directory

Tags: fluentd

Fluentd accepts CSV filenames to log. But that too implies a prior knowledge of file-names.

```
<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/nginx/*.log
  tag logging
  format /^(?<time>.+) \[(?<level>[^\]]+)\] *(?<message>.*)$/
  time_format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
</source>
```

Is there an option or a hack to do something logically equivalent to- `path /var/log/*.log`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the tail_ex plugin.  It allows you to use file globbing in the path.