# Is it possible to monitor a whole directory with fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I would like to set up log forwarding as part of a deployment process. The activity of the machines will be different but they will all log to specific places (notably `/var/log`).

**Is it possible to configure `fluentd` so that it monitors a whole directory?** (including the ability to pick up files which pop-up while it is active)

I know that [`in_tail`](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_tail) can do this for a given, specified file but the documentation does not mention a whole directory.

---

There is an ideal [exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703413/fluentd-tail-plugin-tail-all-files-in-a-directory) of this question from 2014 which points to the [`tail_ex` plugin](https://github.com/yosisa/fluent-plugin-tail-ex). Unfortunately its description mentions that

> Deprecated: Fluentd has the features of this plugin since 0.10.45. So,
>   the plugin no longer maintained

I still could not find the mentioned features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the wildcard support within Fluentd's `in_tail` plugin this is absolutely possible. In the `path` section you would specify the `/var/log/*` directory and Fluentd will automatically skip files that are non-readable.

Additionally, if you write new files to this directory Fluentd will periodically scan based on the configuration item `https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_tail#refreshinterval`

Some notes: If you use [Treasure Data's](http://www.treasuredata.com) packaged version of Fluentd, td-agent then you need to ensure that the files you want to tail are readable by the `td-agent` user that is provisioned as part of that install.

Lastly, if you need to securely read these files you may consider [Treasure Data's Enterprise Fluentd offering](http://www.treasuredata.com/fluentd)

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I missed that in the doc I linked. Would you know whether the path is recursive (i.e. whether subdirectories can be watched as well via something like `/hello/*/*.log` or `/hello/**/*.log` or another incantation)?

Comment: The path is recursive and uses Linux glob expansion to determine all available paths.